# Is it possible to define shortcode and then cal in template file - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a file **a.php** where I have defined `<a href="abc.com/page_id=11?key=123">link</a>`

I have created a custom template **custom.php** and created a page at wordpress backend that has **page_id=11**

So, from **a.php** I am sending a user to **custom.php** with the help of **page_id and then fetching the key=123**

This is working fine..

The only problem is that I am not sure about **page_id = 11**.

Is it possible to get the same using the shortcode so as I can avoid using the **page_id** in my template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function to create a `shortcode` to get the `page id`

```
function id_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // extract the variables, if there is no ID attr, the default is 1
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 1
    ), $atts ) );
    // set page id to either the id attr which defaults to one.
    $page_id = $id;
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    return 
}
// shortcode registration
add_shortcode( 'getid', 'id_shortcode' );
```

Then you can simply use **`[getid]`** `shortcode` on your page to get that `page id`

I hope i have understood and solved your problem...

And you can call this shortcode also in your template file

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[getid]"); ?>
```